# how do I query a range of table that's named after date

Tags: mysql, sql, database, google-bigquery

I would like to query data from a range of tables. But the table names are named after the date of the table creation, for instance: `2017-01-10`, `2017-01-11` etc. After doing some research I found out that the `TABLE_DATE_RANGE` feature may suit my need however, the table name has to be in the format of `<prefix><date>` for instance:

```
SELECT * 
FROM TABLE_DATE_RANGE([mydataset.sea_weather_],
                TIMESTAMP("2016-05-01"),
                TIMESTAMP("2016-05-09"))
```

The problem again is that the tables that I want to query from don't carry a prefix, but I would still like to do a query from a range of the tables/dates. Please advise.

Comment: You are not using MySQL.  My best guess is BigQuery, so I tagged appropriately.

Comment: the database is mysql, but thanks.

Comment: oops, sorry - i thought you said you are using mysql :o) so are you expecting answer for BigQuery?

Answer (score 0):

> After doing some research I found out that the TABLE_DATE_RANGE feature may suit my need however, the table name has to be in the format of `<prefix><date>`

I think your finding is not correct

Try below to query let's say previous week tables (assuming table name is of YYYMMDD format - so no prefixes):

for BigQuery Legacy SQL

```sql
#legacySQL
SELECT <list of fields ...>
FROM (TABLE_DATE_RANGE([yourProject:yourDataset.], 
        DATE_ADD(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), -7 - DAYOFWEEK(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()) + 2, 'DAY'), 
        DATE_ADD(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), -1 - DAYOFWEEK(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()) + 2, 'DAY')
      ))
GROUP BY 1, 2, 3
ORDER BY 1, 2, 3
```

You can test it with [githubarchive:day]  public dataset

```sql
#legacySQL
SELECT 
  STRFTIME_UTC_USEC(created_at, "%Y%m%d") AS d,
  DAYOFWEEK(created_at) AS dow,
  DAYOFWEEK(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()) AS cdow,
  COUNT(1) AS rows
FROM (TABLE_DATE_RANGE([githubarchive:day.], 
        DATE_ADD(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), -7 - DAYOFWEEK(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()) + 2, 'DAY'), 
        DATE_ADD(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), -1 - DAYOFWEEK(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()) + 2, 'DAY')
      ))
GROUP BY 1, 2, 3
ORDER BY 1, 2, 3
```

For BigQuery Standard SQL

```sql
#standardSQL
SELECT 
  DATE(created_at) AS d,
  EXTRACT(DAYOFWEEK FROM DATE(created_at)) AS dow,
  EXTRACT(DAYOFWEEK FROM CURRENT_DATE()) AS cdow,
  COUNT(1) AS c
FROM `yourProject.yourDataset.*`
WHERE _TABLE_SUFFIX
  BETWEEN FORMAT_DATE('%Y%m%d',DATE_ADD(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL -7 - EXTRACT(DAYOFWEEK FROM CURRENT_DATE()) + 2 DAY))
  AND FORMAT_DATE('%Y%m%d',DATE_ADD(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL -1 - EXTRACT(DAYOFWEEK FROM CURRENT_DATE()) + 2 DAY))
GROUP BY 1, 2, 3
ORDER BY 1, 2, 3
```

Be aware that in Standard SQL the issue can rise for such pattern if you have views in your dataset - you will get error like `Error: Views cannot be queried through prefix`
In this case - you can use below "trick" for example (assuming that views will not match that (2*) wildcard

```sql
#standardSQL
SELECT 
  DATE(created_at) AS d,
  EXTRACT(DAYOFWEEK FROM DATE(created_at)) AS dow,
  EXTRACT(DAYOFWEEK FROM CURRENT_DATE()) AS cdow,
  COUNT(1) AS c
FROM `githubarchive.day.2*`
WHERE CONCAT('2', _TABLE_SUFFIX ) 
  BETWEEN FORMAT_DATE('%Y%m%d',DATE_ADD(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL -7 - EXTRACT(DAYOFWEEK FROM CURRENT_DATE()) + 2 DAY))
  AND FORMAT_DATE('%Y%m%d',DATE_ADD(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL -1 - EXTRACT(DAYOFWEEK FROM CURRENT_DATE()) + 2 DAY))
GROUP BY 1, 2, 3
ORDER BY 1, 2, 3
```